# MySQL Workbench: No objects selected

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I have installed MySQL Workbench in my machine. But now I'm unable to select a table on left hand side. Here's what I have currently:

[image]

How can I get to the tables in my database?

Comment: Can you add OS info to your question?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Watch out in which area you are in MySQL Workbench. Currently you have the admin section active. Use the tabs to switch to the SQL section to view your db objects:

[image]

Vs.

[image]

Btw, you screenshot looks strange. This "No objects selected" box is from the SQL section but shown (much too large) as overlay over some parts of the admin sidebar section. Whatever you did to get to this state is really interesting. If you see this frequently I recommend that you file a [bug report](http://bugs.mysql.com) with all necessary details (you ommitted here), like the OS, WB version etc.

Update:

Maybe you can solve this by not using the combined mode for admin + sql sections. If you switch that off (what I recommend anyway) you get 2 tab pages as I have shown in my screenshots. For that go to the settings and disable combined mode (the last option in that screenshot):

[image]

Also, make sure you have the latest version of MySQL Workbench (atm. 6.3.3).

Comment: I can't able to switch tab to sql section

Comment: Even after restarting WB? That text field is in the way, right? Does it appear so wrongly every time?

Comment: yes exactly, I have reinstall wb , but it show the same

Comment: OS is probably Linux? Did you try resizing windows, the splitters between them etc.? Somehow this over-large status control is the real problem.

Answer (score 129):

pull the scroll bar downward. i had the same issue but all i needed to do was to extend the navigation menu.

[image]

Comment: My schema tree was not showing at all. This guided me towards the solution. The Object info and Session tab was right at the top of the left pane and dragging it down the Schema tree was actually there it just had a zero height.

Comment: @KobusKleynhans I had exactly this issue. Turns out the panel was minimised and had 0 height, had to drag Object Info and Session tab switcher down. I think your suggestion deserves a separate answer. Thank you!

Comment: Same "problem" in 2023... thanks

Comment: Same i think this problem is in mac version , in windows version it's having some height by default.

Answer (score 4):

The configuration setting worked for me:

Edit -> Preferences -> SQL Editor -> Sidebar -> Combine Management Tools and Schema Tree (unselected)

This enables the navigation tabs 'Management' and 'Schemas' in the sidebar.

GNU/Linux, MySQL Workbench 6.2 Community, Version 6.2.5.0 build 397 (64 bits)