# Mysql-Workbench table browser pane is lost

Tags: mysql, linux, mysql-workbench

In my Linux system, I use Mysql-Workbench for db management. Today, I can't see the table browser in the left pane. I checked the menus but it seems it is not a preference issue...
Here is a screenshot:

[image]

Did you have such a problem before? How can I fix it?

Comment: From memory, there should be two tabs at the bottom of the panel (Administration and Schemas). Do you have them?

Comment: Try this [clik this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29862518/mysql-workbench-no-objects-selected) Hoping this helps You.

Comment: Shivaraj Nico207 thanks! I had missed that point.